# Is there any way to start a Docker container in detached mode?

Tags: docker

I am a Docker rookie so my use of concepts and terminology below may be flawed.

I think I understand the notion of creating a container (via `docker create`), and of starting a container so created (via `docker start`).  I also understand less clearly but still somewhat that `docker run` is used to simultaneously create and run a container.  Do correct me if I'm wrong.

Unless I've missed something, if I want to start a container so that it is detached, my only option is `docker run -d`.

What I don't understand is: suppose I have already created my container, and it's stopped, and now I want to start it detached.  How do I do that?  Or is that the wrong way to think about it?

I ran into this conceptual misunderstanding (I'm sure that's what it is) by trying to run container twice using below command:
`docker -d --name=fred my/image`

**The second time I got:**

> docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The name "/image" is already in use by container [...]

Fine; I understand now that this tries to create two containers with the same name which quite clearly cannot happen.  But that led me to this conceptual question: if I have a container that is, say, stopped, how can I start it up in detached mode?

I told you I was a rookie.  Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Unless you specifically attach (`-a` or `-i` options) when you start the container, by definition you are detached.

Creating a container simply builds the filesystem layer.  Starting it runs the `ENTRYPOINT` (or CMD) process.  Run does both the create and the start, as you surmised.  So you cannot "attach" to a created container... there is no process to attach to.

Here I create a container (all this does is create the filesystem layer):

```
$ docker create \
    --name=test \
    centos:latest \
    /bin/sh -c "while true; do echo hello world; sleep 1; done"
```

Note that the `STATUS` is `Created`:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
9d5bf75a8077        centos:latest            "/bin/sh -c 'while tr"   15 seconds ago      Created                                        test
```

It isn't running yet.  Now start it without attaching, nothing is printed to the terminal STDOUT, because I am not attached.  But STDOUT is going to the log-driver (json-file) which you can view with `docker logs`:

```
$ docker start test test
$ docker logs test
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
```

Comment: James, for now formatted your answer. You can get help link while answering the question which you can start using going forward. :)

Comment: Thanks Rao, I looked at the help and tried using backticks.  I've also tried <code></code> but didn't submit it because it didn't look right in the "preview".  Just to get me started... what demarcation did you use on my block?

Comment: @JamesMoser, thanks for your answer.  This is very helpful.  Regarding formatting, start a new line after a blank line and prefix it with four spaces.  Presto; instance block monospace.

Comment: I don't think this fully answers the question. `docker run -itd foo` creates and starts a container, which I can see with `docker ps`. I can access the TTY with `docker attach`. However, if I `create` and then `start` a container, it auto-exits and I cannot see it in `docker ps` and cannot access its TTY. If `docker run` is just a combo of `create` and `start`, how do I replicate `docker run -itd` behavior with those commands? So far the only "answer" here it to use `docker run`.

Comment: Answered my own question. The `-it` flags take effect during the `create` step, not the `start` step. I mistakenly assumed they can be changed at start-time (another rookie here). In order to replicate the behavior I described, you should `docker create -it foo` and then `docker start` it. Then it will appear in `docker ps` and can be attached to.

Answer (score 9):

Here is how it works.

**Running a docker container `busybox`, a tiny linux image** in detached mode and container name is `testso`

```
bash $ docker run -itd --name testso busybox
b60d0847bb81065d5f5d4b3a3acff3102d03e7a8a084c0770da4487427787479
```

You can see container running

```
bash $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
b60d0847bb81        busybox             "sh"                7 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds                            testso
```

Now stopping the above container `testso` and check no container is running.

```
bash $ docker stop testso
testso
bash $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Now,**your question addressed** by starting earlier stopped container `testso` and see the container running in the background.

```
bash $ docker start testso
testso
bash $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
b60d0847bb81        busybox             "sh"                46 seconds ago      Up 2 seconds                            testso
```

So, when the container is `docker run` with `-d` option first, the container can just use `docker start containerid` which automatically run in detached mode.

Hope this is helpful.

UPDATE:
Regarding running for second time, as you rightly pointed there are two options and out of it :

1. Instead of running it using the command `docker run --name=mycontainer image`, you may just start the existing container which you just trying and the above answer helps.
2. Wipe out the existing container and re-run `docker run --name=mycontainer image`.
   To wipe you existing container, use command - `docker rm -f mycontainer`

Comment: Laird, would you please check if the above answer helps to understand better? And does it resolve the problem you have?